# "WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy classes"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services

I'm working on an application that makes asynchronous calls to the WebService.

I added a proxy class to make asynchronous calls. The code compiles and runs properly, however whenever I try to double-click the proxy class in solution explorer (Visual Studio 2008) I am presented with a page

To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: 
WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy classes.

My proxy class is already defined this way

```
namespace AsyncCaller
{
    [WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "AsyncRequestSoap", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class AsyncCallerProxy : SoapHttpClientProtocol
    {
        public AsyncCallerProxy()
        {
            this.Url = "http://localhost/MyAsyncService/AsyncService.asmx";
        }
```

So I can't see the reason for the error.

This is a very minor issue since I can still run the application, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same problem here..
Just decorate your proxy class with the following attribute

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]

to get rid of the useless design mode.

Answer (score 13):

In the properties for the project. In the Build Tab. Select "Generate Serialization assembly:" to Off.

Comment: I actually needed this, apparently the build behavior for "Auto" is different between 'Debug' and 'Release', when switching to release I was getting the error in the title of this thread on one of my ws proxy projects. This fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: Any idea where this option is on a VB.Net Forms Application with Application Framework? There's no "Build" tab :(
EDIT: Nevermind. I found it under "Compile" -> "Advanced Compile Options"